# A problem about self adjoint operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space. $L$ is a self adjoint operator satisfying $\exists A,B>0$ such that $$A||f||^2\leq \langle Lf,f \rangle\leq B||f||^2$$ for any $f$ in $H$.

We need to prove$$ \frac{1}{B}||f||^2\leq\langle L^{-1}f,f\rangle\leq\frac{1}{A}||f||^2$$for any $f$ in $H$.

It is not difficult to conclude that $L$ is invertible. $L$ is injective from the left inquality. And if is not surjective, there exists nonzero $h$ in the orthogonal complement of the range of $L$, thus $A||h||^2\leq \langle Lh,h\rangle =0 $ ,which is a contradiction.

For the formula we need to prove, if we let $f=Lf$, then we can get a formula that is similar with the one we already know, but there still is a difference. Although I suppose it is not hard to prove, I didn't come up with a proof. Maybe there is a trick I ignored.

Comment: Your proof that $L$ is invertible is flawed. If $L$ is not surjective, that does not imply there exists non-zero $h$ in the orthogonal complement of the range of $L$. This is only the case if $L$ is bounded, which you first need to show. Also, you show $L$ is bijective, which is different from invertible, as invertible requires $L^{-1}$ to be bounded as well.

Comment: @SmileyCraft sorry. I left a condition that L is self adjoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about what tools you may use. But here's some idea. Note that $L$ is a positive self-adjoint element of $B(H)$. By the assumption, we have
$$
\langle Af,f\rangle\leq \langle Lf,f\rangle\leq \langle Bf,f\rangle
$$ meaning that$$
AI\leq L\leq BI.
$$ This means $\sigma(L)\subset [A,B]$, and by the spectral mapping theorem, we get
$$
\sigma(L^{-1})\subset [\frac{1}{B}, \frac{1}{A}].
$$ This establishes that
$$
\frac{1}{B}I\leq L^{-1}\leq \frac{1}{A}I,
$$ as desired. Another approach uses square root $K = \sqrt{L}$ of $L$. By the assumption, we have
$$
A||f||^2\leq||Kf||^2 \leq B||f||^2. 
$$Hence it holds that
$$
\frac{1}{B}||f||^2\leq||K^{-1}f||^2 \leq \frac{1}{A}||f||^2.
$$ This implies what we wanted:
$$
\frac{1}{B}||f||^2\leq\langle L^{-1}f,f\rangle\leq\frac{1}{A}||f||^2.
$$